# how can i quickly select/change two keyframes of one object

Tags: graph-editor

I have this situation in the graph editor:

[image]

Essentially i filter via "z loc" and all objects are currently animated on the same position.

Now i want to offset each of these two keyframes a bit.

Currently i am doing this, and it sounds too complicated, i am pretty sure there must be a better way:

1. i select the z location on the left for object 1

[image]

2. then i press shift-H to hide all other curves
3. then i box-select my two keyframes

[image]

4. then i press G X 5 to move them
5. i press alt-H to show all and repeat from step 1 for all objects

Yes, i know about the offset-animation-add-on but i am curious for a better manual way.

EDIT: ok, i just found out that double click on the left side selects at least the curve + handles, but still i am looking for something faster...

Comment: Not sure to understand what you want to do? The same Z shift for all objects?

Comment: @lemon: sorry if it wasn't clear. No, not the same. I know i could scale it. I want to manually move all, but independently. So for each object, i want to select  just the two keyframes (there exist more, that's why i box-select) and then move them with cursor or G X 5.

Comment: so, once filtered on "z loc", select all in the channel tree and box select the keyframes?

Comment: i want to box-select only the two keyframes of one object, then do something with that ...and then quickly box-select (or other if possible) the two keyframes of the next object